# Problem with camera view

Tags: camera

My camera view is not right. i'm new in blender so i dunno how to fix it, i have tried everything but can make it right the camera view on the right seems to have like a lens that makes it look that way, Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

there are two settings viewport focal length (35, in your case) and camera focal length (30.72 in your case), 35 would be default.

on your picture i cant really see a problem, you just have zoomed out while being inside the camera so you se the fisheye-distortion of your camera around the real sensor area. if thats the problem just zoom in.

Your render should look good with 30.72 focal length. If you want ist exactly as in Viewport put it to 35 in Camera-Lens menu.

but maybe i'm missing something?
Greetings AM